# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger which will check table A for any insert or update record and will update my table B with a new record but getting below error:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

**Below are my tables:**

```
create table A(count int, trigger_name varchar(25));
create table B(trigger_name varchar(25), time_created Timestamp);
```

**Here is my trigger:**

```
create trigger record_after_insert after insert on A for each row 
Begin
insert into B values (NEW.trigger_name, sysdate());
End;
```

I am using MySQL version 5.7.13. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, did you check the manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `record_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `A`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into B values (NEW.trigger_name, sysdate());
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I tried the solution you mentioned but that is also not woring and now I am getting the Super privilege error. I tried setting SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1; but that is also I am not able to run as it says that i don't have super privileges.

Comment: Your MySQL account needs the SUPER privilege. See documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

I was not having the privileges on the database to run the trigger after granting the privileges i was able to run the trigger statement.